# Instantiate typed, concrete type from generic type map?

Tags: typescript

If I have an abstract class that is extended by a multitude of subclasses:

```js
export abstract class Model {
  // ...
}

@ModelName('Job')
export class Job extends Model {
  // ...
}

// etc.
```

And stored together to be able to be looked up later:

```js
const modelTypes: [new (...args: any) => Model] = [Job, /* etc */];
```

How can I write a function to construct a concrete type, while preserving the Typescript compiler's ability to reason about the created type? I've tried the following function:

```js
public createModel<T extends Model>(modelName: string, modelData: any): T {
    const modelCtor = modelTypes.find(mt => mt.prototype.modelName === modelName);
    return new modelCtor(modelData);
}
```

However, this gives me the compilation error of:

```
'Model' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Model'.
```

I can adjust the return type of the function to be `Model`, but this effectively means I can't appropriately type the returned value:

```js
createModel<Job>('Job', data); // type is of type `Model`, even if I were to provide a useless generic parameter.
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w8A9PN), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (with no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRJqnw) meet your needs?  You won't be able to use a decorator to mutate the type of a class (see [microsoft/TypeScript#4881](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881)) so the best you can do is to use it mixin-function-style.  But with that caveat, you should be able to give the type system enough information to understand the mapping from model name to model type.